# Stop Notepad++ warning if file has been modified from outside

Tags: notepad++

How can I stop the warning that appears in Notepad++ if the file is modified from an external program or application?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Settings -> Preferences -> MISC. tab

In the section that says `File Status Auto Detection` make sure that `Enable` is unchecked

Answer (score 65):

Settings → Preferences → Misc. →  Uncheck Enable under **File Status Auto-Detection**

Also, as [Jet](https://superuser.com/users/180465/jet) pointed out, you can also have 'Update silently' checked if you want it to auto-update the file.

[image: Uncheck 'Enable' to disable update detection or check both 'Enable' and 'Update silently' to automatically update once a change is made.]

Comment: Or check "Update Silently" if you want to update it automatically.

Comment: Wish you could have only the files in "tail"/monitoring mode update silently. (...goes off to look for existing GitHub Issue or open one...)