How can one close all non-existing files at once in Notepad++?
When closing a non-existing file in Notepad++, one gets this window:

How can one close all non-existing files at once in Notepad++? I use Windows.

Like a macro maybe? Or some UI-based control?

@music2myear thanks, I'll take anything.

You can turn off all file status checks, https://superuser.com/questions/206226/stop-notepad-warning-if-file-has-been-modified-from-outside, but if you do that, you risk losing wok.
